# 'module' is not defined error for babel.config.js

Tags: typescript

I have simple [LinkedList implementation](https://github.com/alvinseville7cf/LinkedList/tree/unit-tests) written on TypeScript. The problem is in [babel.config.js](https://github.com/alvinseville7cf/LinkedList/blob/unit-tests/babel.config.js):

```js
module.exports.presets = [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
];
```

vs code shows an `'module' is not defined` error in it. How to fix it? I use vs code 1.60 and Node v14.17.4.